# PDO execution and bindparam

Tags: php, security, pdo

If i do this:

```
$qry->execute(array($usuario,$pass));
```

instead of this:

```
$qry->bindParam(1, $usuario);
$qry->bindParam(2, $pass);
$qry->execute();
```

does this give a security problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, they are semantically identical

And it's specified in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> Execute the prepared statement. If the prepared statement included parameter markers, you must either:
>
> - call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter markers: bound variables pass their value as input and receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers
> - or pass an array of input-only parameter values

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not. It will work fine.